# Unit Test Code Coverage Reporting

Tags: java

I have been asked by my scrum master to provide him a report of a time sequence of all unit tests created and which developer created them. (He wants to get a measure on what developers have been adding unit tests).

Our environment is using Jenkins and SonarQube. SonarQube does provide test coverage reports, but I cannot find a way to report as above.

**Question** Is it possible to generate a report like this? How?

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is typically the producer system, which performs builds and deployments jobs.

SonarCube does perform analysis of the code base, stuff like how many lines the methods have, how complex the control flow is. So it is about code quality.

To perform your task you have to detect the unit tests in your source code base.
In our Java code base an approach would be to find the methods which have a
`@Test` annotation.

Assigning these code lines to developers is a bit more tricky, you would need to pull that information from your source code control system (git, Subversion, darcs, ..).
Usually you can retrieve which line in the code base was modified by which developer.

So it is possible in general.

The specifics depend on your environment (programming language, operating system, source code control system).

Comment: thanks for the answer. As you say it is possible to generate a report, but it looks like it will require quite a bit of work (i.e. to write something to extract the meta data). I was hoping more that there was a tool already out there that I could use? Or if SonarQube could do it?

Comment: I just noted the Java tag. So what OS and SCCS do you use?

Comment: We are using WIndows and Git

Comment: I am not aware of an existing tool. You need to identify the lines in your java files which are unit tests and then use `git blame` to retrieve its author. I would probably do this in some scripting language like Ruby. You can try to repost your question on Stack Overflow to reach more eye balls.